# Create a fifth column as list with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have to make a fifth column in my array but when I run the script it gives me that :

```
Column1 : 
Column2 : 
Column3 : 
Column4 : 
Column5 :
```

I would like to get this:

```
Column1  Column2   Column3   Column4  Column5
-------  -------   -------   -------  -------
```

The code I'm using allows to display four columns and remove the matching cells in the array.

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\test1.csv -Delimiter ';'

$ref = [ordered]@{}
$columns = foreach ($i in 0..7) { ,[Collections.ArrayList]@() }

foreach ($row in $csv) {
    $value = $row.Column1
    $ref[$value] = $true
    $columns[0].add($value) >$null
}

foreach ($row in $csv) {
    $i = 1
    foreach ($col in 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4') {
        $value = $row.$col
        if (!$ref[$value]) {
            $columns[$i].add($value) >$null
        }
        $i++
    }
}

$maxLine = ($columns | select -expand Count | measure -Maximum).Maximum - 1
$csv = foreach ($i in 0..$maxLine) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Column1 = $columns[0][$i]
        Column2 = $columns[1][$i]
        Column3 = $columns[2][$i]
        Column4 = $columns[3][$i]

    }
}


$csv
```

The lists have been build separately then joined in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `Format-Table` cmdlet:

```
$csv | Format-Table
```

Comment: I thought that wouldn't work, surely because I had the another code, so thank you.